# how to merging multiple key and values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

hello i am thinking if how to combine a array with their same key value pairs

```
Array
(
    [category_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => Apple
            [1] => Cow
        )

    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => Fruit
            [1] => Meat
        )
)
```

i already used **array_combine** but the expecting output was not like that output.

the output i want to see is like this.

```
1 , Apple , Fruit
2 , Cow , Meat
```

i dont know if how to do this. hopefully you can help me. thank you very much

Comment: [array_column()](https://php.net/array_column) then [implode()](https://php.net/implode)?

Comment: Side note: it's better to share the output of `var_export` than `print_r`, because then anyone can easily copy the contents to their editor for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Direct Output

If you just need to output your array directly to the page, you could do something like this:

```
foreach($original_array['category_id'] as $key => $categoryid) {
    $product = $original_array['product'][$key];
    $category = $original_array['category'][$key];
    
    echo "{$categoryid} , {$product} , {$category}\n";
}
```

This is pretty simple and only requires a single foreach loop. This is useful if you do not need to use this data multiple times in different places.

---

### Formatted Array Output

If you may need to use this later in code, I would create a new array with the data in the loop above.
This is probably overkill if you don't ever need to access this data again.

```
$output = [];
foreach($original_array['category_id'] as $key => $categoryid) {
    $product = $original_array['product'][$key];
    $category = $original_array['category'][$key];
    
    $output[] = ['category_id' => $categoryid, 'product' => $product, 'category' => $category];
}
```

This would make `$output` be something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 1
            [product] => Apple
            [category] => Fruit
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 2
            [product] => Cow
            [category] => Meat
        )

)
```

Which, of course, is trivial to output in your required format.

```
foreach($output as $values) {
    echo "{$values['categoryid']} , {$values['product']} , {$values['category']}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple foreach loop seems the best approach in this case

```
$original = [
    'category_id' => [1, 2],
    'product' => ["Apple", "Cow"],
    'category' => ["Fruit", "Meat"]
];

foreach ( $original['category_id'] as $key => $v) {
    printf("%d, %s, %s\n", $v, $original['product'][$key], $original['category'][$key]);
}
```

RESULT

```
1, Apple, Fruit
2, Cow, Meat
```

Answer (score 0):

Another dynamic way to do this, is to use [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column) and [`implode()`](https://php.net/implode).

```
$array = [
    'category_id' => [1,       2],
    'product'     => ['Apple', 'Cow'],
    'category'    => ['Fruit', 'Meat'],
];

// Gets the number of items in the first subarray:
$numColumns = count(reset($array));

// Loop around the columns:
for ($idx = 0; $idx < $numColumns; $idx++)
{
    // Print the column $idx, separated by ', ':
    echo implode(', ', array_column($array, $idx)) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1, Apple, Fruit
2, Cow, Meat
```